# Azure Health Check end point code changes ASP NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I need to add code to ASP NET Restful Api to enable Azure Health Check. Most resources I found are about Net Core. I am looking for reference and advice on how to add the code changes in Asp Net Restful Api code base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Health Check needs a path that it can ping to monitor the availability of your app. That path is just an endpoint you have defined. .Net Core / .Net has built-in support for creating health endpoints, see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/health-checks?view=aspnetcore-7.0) and for .Net Framework you could use a lib like [this one](https://github.com/ritterim/RimDev.AspNet.Diagnostics.HealthChecks).

In its most basic form you can create one like this

```
public class HealthController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IHttpActionResult GetHealth()
    {
        return Ok(new { Status = "Healthy" });
    }
}
```

Key takeaway: there is nothing magic about a health endpoint. You can create the most simple one or an advanced one that also checks dependencies like databases etc.As long as the endpoint returns status code between 200-299 the instance will be considered healthy.

Comment: Do I have to use  the build-in support for creating health endpoint? If not, can I just use routes.MapRoute to config a route for the health check end point ?

Comment: No you don't have to use the built-in endpoints, you can safely use MapRoute